# Extra width on Mobile views - Can't figure out what's causing the extra space

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on making my site responsive. Here's a link: http://www.iPwn.com.

I'm using Google Chromes device mode, and using smaller views (like the iPhone 4, or 320px width) I keep getting extra width and a horizontal scroll bar.

**Note:** This is strictly for widths around 320px.. anything bigger I haven't fixed up (yet because I've been stuck on this)

I've went through one by one and removed every element, looked at the code piece by piece to try and figure out what's extending the layout horizontally. I can't find it anywhere.

At first I thought it was the navigation at the top, however I removed that completely and it was still there.

Any ideas on why it's doing this?

-edit- 
I just tested it again because of comments, and it works in Firefox, and for some reason it suddenly works in Chrome when you resize the browser window. However it's still not working in the "Device Mode", and also not on my iPhone itself.

Here's a screen shot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUfAK.jpg

Comment: Can you post some code? I have tested it on firefox and I don't see the problem. Maybe should you explain the problem more.

Comment: Tested in Chrome and I can't see any scroll bars.. can you add a screenshot?

Comment: You're right. Seems to be working fine in Firefox. It's not working in Chrome or on my iPhone though.

Comment: Even with your image I don't get the problem.

Comment: top right of the image "Primary Menu" is cut off and it adds a horizontal scroll. For some reason, it's reading 336 pixels of width, when it should only be 320px.

Comment: add some code. With only a link can't we work. add the relevant html,css and javascript code

Comment: I added a screen shot because Vlad asked for one. I gave a link to the site above for the code. I don't know what code you want me to add. If you open the link up on your mobile phone, or in google chromes Device Mode you should see the same problem. I've tested it on another iPhone and my girlfriends Galaxy now too.. and they all show the same problem as in the screen shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you have problem with your header section. it taking 336px instead of 320px.

```
#page{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

hope this may fix your problem

above solution was quick fix for a time. it was not perfect solution; technically speaking.

The real problem is with your **#blogFeed** section.

**Your Style**

```
#blogFeed ul.postList {
  margin-left: 5%!important;
}

#blogFeed ul.postList {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 0px!important;
  padding-left: 0px!important;
}
```

Its making your container of 105%(320 + 16) i.e **336px** in width so original size of container is now 336px instead of 320px;

problem with header : The problem with using **"fixed"** positioning is that it takes the element out of flow. thus it can't be re-positioned relative to its parent. so now with width : 100% to FIXED header its taking 336px and goes out of viewport(of 320px).

I hope you may understand this.

Comment: That did it! Do you have any reasoning why that did worked? I'm really confused about what's going on here.

Comment: BTW your website is not optimize at all you can check it on [gtmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com) and may found possible fixes

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The cards have a width of 50%, BUT remember that the `<ul>` has a padding-left.

2 solutions

1) `ul{ padding:0px; }`
2) `cards{width:calc(50% - (ulpadding-left/2) )}`

Comment: I actually haven't gotten to that screen size yet. I've been stuck on the smaller view (around 320px), which doesn't have them side by side.